# Debugging an RTD-to-ADC conditioning circuit

Tags: adc, rtd

As a software developer, I got myself into a bit of a pickle trying to make a 3-wire Pt100 temperature probe readable by a 3.3v microcontroller's ADC pin.

I followed page 4 of [this MCP document](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00687c.pdf) which describes how to do exactly what I'm trying to do, and breadboarded everything up. I adjusted the gain of the Sallen-Key filter by changing R_11 from 20kohms to 88kohms.

I've got the following problems: my multimeter is telling me the current source is putting out way less than 1mA (the needle barely budges), and the output voltage predicted by [this simulator](https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/#?id=shk4n7) at the end of the Sallen-Key filter should be 2.954V, but I'm reading about 0.125V.

I tried swapping out the op-amp IC and the resistors, but I get the same result.

[image: The breadboard. The current source is on the left size of the MCP309, and the Sallen-Key filter is on the right side.]

So here are my questions:

- Is there something obviously wrong with my breadboard that I missed?
- Why does the current source need two op-amps? Could that be why I might be having trouble?
- Is there an easier way to do this?

[image]

Comment: I think we're going to need a schematic from you. And where are your power and ground connections for the op amp?

Comment: The schematic was in the OP: https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/#?id=shk4n7

Sorry, should have made that more obvious.

Comment: The op-amps I'm using are on the MCP 609: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/11177f.pdf

Comment: Oh… hang on… am I supposed to use the MCP 609's V_DD and V_SS pins?

Comment: An opamp with no power supply is a strange concept..

Comment: Aha, I'll give that a shot. Derp.

Comment: Okay, that was the problem – everything looks right as rain now. Do either of you want to answer it so I can give you an upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have connected power and ground for your op amp. That's an easy thing to overlook when you are starting out.